# Is there an idiosyncratic way to parse nested JSON in Ruby?

Tags: json, ruby

Given an arbitrary JSON string such as:

```json
"{\"foo\":\"{\\\"bar\\\":\\\"baz\\\"}\"}"
```

Is there a method Ruby JSON or general idiosyncrasy in Ruby to recursively parse JSON so that the result is:

```rb
{ foo: { bar: :baz } }
```

What I'm **not** looking for:

```rb
o = JSON.parse(j)

JSON.parse!(o[:foo])
```

Comment: I think this gem will help you: https://github.com/spaceghoul/json_deep_parse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really. The reason is that a JSON string is, well, just a string, so there's no way to *just know* if it's parsable JSON.

You could *try* and parse everything as JSON like so:

```
def recursive_parse_hash_from_json(str)
  parsed = JSON.parse(str)
  parsed.reduce({}) do |memo, (key, val)|
    new_val = val.is_a?(String) ? recursive_parse_hash_from_json(val) : val
    memo.merge({ key =>  val})
  end
rescue JSON::ParserError
  str
end

json = {"a" => { "b" => "c" }.to_json, "d" => "e"}.to_json
recursive_parse_hash_from_json(json)
# => {"a"=>{"b"=>"c"}, "d"=>"e"}
```

But this has edge cases - what if one of the strings just *happens* to be valid JSON, but isn't intended to be so?

Depending on your use case, the above method may work for you though. However I wouldn't recommend doing this for anything other than analytics. E.g. if you're working with user-supplied strings and this actually controls business logic your application, you woudln't want to risk parsing something as the wrong data type.